# Revert a pushed merge to erase local undesired changes pushed by mistake

Tags: git, git-revert

I pushed a merge in a parent repository with submodules.
Lets say I merged my `main` branch in my `feature/Foo` branch.
By mistake I pushed along with the merge, local changes and locally created new files that should not have been pushed.

For example I have:

LOCAL CHANGES: (uncommitted changes)

- 5 locally changed files
- 5 locally new files

MERGE CHANGES: (coming from the `main` branch)

- 5 change by the merge files
- 5 added new by the merge files

Now I need to revert the pushed merge.
I know how git revert works to revert a commit, creates just a commit with the opposite changes, so when reverting a merge, it reverts all the changes.
Local changes + changes carried along with the merge are reverted, so an opposite change is created to undo all the changed/created files performed in the merge commit.

**Solution I adopted:**

So to leave the version as I wanted, this is, with the changes only brought by the MERGE CHANGES and not the local changes, I have to file by file select/discard the cahnges I want in the revert commit, this is, check the log manually and discard the changes I do not want for the revert.
These are the ones brought by the merge because I want to revert only the files changed/added locally by mistake.

**Why?**

Because if I revert all the changes, I am reverting also the ones brought by the merge and after If I re-merege that the comment with the changes I need, nothing happens, because merge flow was solved already.
By these I mean that the `main` branch changes are not brought again to the `feature/Foo` branch. Seems that even though I am 2 commits ahead from the original merge after the revert, the merge flow was solved in the original merge commit (check "Final commit to restore original merge" in the explanatory graph).

**My desire:**

Get to know the way to do this with git, and not manually checking the log of each of the file for a selective revert.
Ideally, not removing remote branches/commits an in the safest of the ways. Would not matter if the revert appears in the history.

**Explanatory graph:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is a lot easier to simply create a new commit with some of the local files checked out from an older version. No need to revert the merge and then to apply fancy magic to this merge commit :)

It should be as simple as:

```
git checkout commit-before-merge -- file1 file2 file3
git commit -m 'Remove accidental local changes'
```

Description: copy the content of the specified files from the commit before the merge. Create a commit with these changes. This effectively "reverts" those changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I see your point and your solution is actually much more simple than the one I adopted, however the point is that the selection of the files that were added from local changes and by the merge, must be set manually in the checkout of your proposal. Imagine that you have lots of changes, and instead to do that manually (so error prone), I wonder if there might be some "mecanical/automatic" way handle this with git and not manually. By this I mean to avoid selective checkout of files as the number of the changes in the commit could be huge.

Comment: @rustyBucketBay maybe I missed that from your question, but since the merge commit contains both "real" changes and "local" changes, how would Git know which changes are to revert and which are not? Somehow you need to specify which changes should be kept and which should be reverted

Comment: by "real" changes I undestang "comming from the merge". Yeah that is actually the whole point of my question. I know it so I can revert that manually, that is the solution I adopted. My question is, that as also git might get to know which changes are coming from where (local/merge), how this can be done in another way that assures that the carefull commit reverter doesn´t mess more up the mess he is already in :)

Comment: more that reverting the changes of the previous commit, I would like maybe to "remove" also th merge itself, so that if I re-merge, those changes are once again brought as changes to be committed to my brach. If I revert, the re-merge does not bring anything, as the merge of that files was previously solved, and the re-merge does not bring those back to my `feature/Foo`...

Comment: @rustyBucketBay I still don't understand, sorry :) What do you mean by "changes coming from a merge"? Do you mean that it was a "dirty" merge, i.e. the merge commit contains changes from neither parents (changes that were added to the merge commit directly, not from an existing branch)?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I am not making myself understood. The changes are coming from two sources. Local changes, or from the merge. By "from the merge" I mean from the branch that I am merging, so from the `main` branch (check explanatory graph in the question). ok @knittl?

Comment: @rustyBucketBay changes in a merge commit can come from 3 sources: the source branch (feature/foo (?)), the target branch (main) and from resolving merge conflicts (a "dirty" merge). You can also "resolve" conflicts even if there were no conflicts – this is were it really gets ugly. But which one is it for you? Are all "local/unintended changes" contained in a single commit? Or are they part of the same commit with "real/intended changes"? I have looked at your image, but it's still not clear to me how exactly those changes ended up in the merge commit. Can you provide the CLI commands?

Comment: `(changes that were added to the merge commit directly, not from an existing branch)?` Changes were comming from another branch(`main`) to the "change receiver branch" by a commit (the "merge commit" in the graph). Just as usual.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228757/discussion-between-knittl-and-rustybucketbay).

Comment: Why not just undo the merge itself? Ok the consequences are messier but the act is simple. Just a hard reset to before the merge.